# How to debug WSL remote extension problems in Windows and contribute to the project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I tried to open the question as an issue but it send me here. I am using VSCode in Windows 10 pro and I am starting to use remote containers and WSL. I often have problems connecting to WSL or the containers inside VSCode, as an example I got this error message a few minutes ago:

```
Failed to connect to the remote extension host server
(Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d 
Ubuntu-20.04 sh -c [ -f '/tmp/vscode-distro-env.drIyvN' ] && cat 
'/tmp/vscode-distro-env.drIyvN' || echo '')
```

I don't know what it means, but most importantly I don't know where to get information. I don't want to stop using this technologies but I just hit a wall. I already viewed Visual Studio Code docs for remote. How can I systematically address these problems to solve my problems and contribute to improving VSCode extension and WSL performance?

Comment: Had exactly the same problem. Shutting down (`wsl --shutdown`) and then restarting wsl fixed it. Actually VSCode offered me to open DevTools after raising this error, which I did, and I believe there you may gather more info about the error (like other previous errors or stacktraces).